# How to insert \n after every nth delimiter without "memory issue" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, out-of-memory

I have a sequence big file with 'Ç' as delimiter.
We need to split at every 40th 'Ç' into a new line.

We have tried using the perl/cut command,but we're getting **"out of memory"** error,because it's a huge file and read/write happens at one time.

**So what I'd want is the following**

***Cut at every 40th delimter occurrence and write/flush to the file and not hold in memory and again do the same for the next 40 and so on.***

Is this achievable in Bash ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit:

This is the command we used in PERL

```
perl -pe 's{Ç}{++$n % 40 ? $& : "\n"}ge' <file_name>
```

Say the data is as follows.

```
123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1Ç123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1ÇmockÇdataÇtest1Ç123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1ÇmockÇdata
```

**I want to cut at (say 3rd delimiter to new line) and assign to a variable or something and flush it to the file so that memory is cleared.**

**Expected output**

```
123ÇasfiÇsadf
test1Ç123Çasfi
sadfÇtest1Çmock
```

Note:It's a huge sequence file.
We're able to achieve the desired output with the above command, but for a larger file it throws memory exception and hence we want to flush the chunks.

Comment: why is that tagged Java?

Comment: I would even say: [java] or [bash or [puthon] ? x)

Comment: Sorry.
Corrected now.

Comment: You should not need to hold the entire file in memory in Perl either, just the chunk to the next delimiter.

Comment: @cdarke This is what we used.
I'm not a shell expert.

perl -pe 's{Ç}{++$n % 40 ? $& : "\n"}ge' <file_name>

Any suggestions??

Comment: @ThanojKrish please add the code you tried to question... and add some sample (say around 200 characters) and show expected output for that... I think `awk` might work out for this use case...

Comment: IMHO, this is a use case where a C prog would be trivial... `#include <stdio.h> int main() { int N=40, c; int n = N; char delim = 'Ç'; while (EOF != (c=getc())) { if (c == delim) { if (--n == 0) { n = N; c = '\n'; } }  putc(c);} return 0; }`

Comment: @Sundeep Added some sample data as well as the command used.  Note: We're able to achieve the desired output with that command,but for a larger file it throws memory exception.

Comment: @SergeBallesta unfortunately we need shell/python script only :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little long, but tell Perl to treat `Ç` as the record separator instead of `\n`; then you can join "lines" as they are read, batch them up, and output them in groups. (My Perl is rusty; there's probably a simpler way to do this.)

```
 perl -ne 'BEGIN {$/="Ç"; $c=0; sub d { chomp $out; print "$out\n"; $out=""; $c=0; }}
           $out .= $_; $c++; &d if $c == 3;
           END { &d }' tmp.txt
```

At the beginning of the script, we change `$/` from its default value of newline to your delimiter; now a "line" is defined as a string ending with a Ç. We initialize a counter `$c` to keep track of how many lines we've read, and we define a subroutine to output the lines accumulated in a variable `$out`, then reset the accumulator and the counter.

For each line of input, we first append that line to the accumulator, increment the counter, then call our output routine if the counter's value reached our target group size.

Finally, we call the output routine at the end of the input to flush any remaining lines in the accumulator.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Works like a charm.
Would be great if you can explain the command a bit more for me to understand.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If Python is an option, here is a port of my proposed C code:

```
# -*- coding: latin1 -*-
import sys

def cvt(fdin, fdout, delim, count):
    curr = count
    while True:
        c = fdin.read(1)
        if c is None or c == '': break
        if c == delim:
            curr -= 1
            if curr == 0:
                curr = count
                c = '\n'
        dummy = fdout.write(c)

cvt(sys.stdin, sys.stdout, 'Ç', 3)
```

It gives as expected:

```
echo "123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1Ç123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1ÇmockÇdataÇtest1Ç123ÇasfiÇsadfÇtest1ÇmockÇdata" | python ess.py
123ÇasfiÇsadf
test1Ç123Çasfi
sadfÇtest1Çmock
dataÇtest1Ç123
asfiÇsadfÇtest1
mockÇdata
```